# select distinct alternative for very large data

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I have a very large data. The query below takes approx 12 seconds to work. Is there a faster alternative? Srno is primary key and multiple occurances of class are there

```
select DISTINCT class
from            data.class
order by        srno desc
```

Comment: Please add more detail: (1) What type of field is it? (2) Is there an index on the field? (3) How many records does your table hold? (4) Can you provide `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: Yes there are indexes . The database has 10 million records